# PWM to DC converter with op amp - slowly but steadily rising output voltage

Tags: arduino, operational-amplifier, pwm, single-supply-op-amp

I assembled a circuit to convert a PWM signal generated by an Arduino to a DC voltage in the range 0..10 V.
[image: PWM to DC voltage converter]

I use the 10k-10u RC filter to convert the PWM signal to DC voltage in the range 0..5 V, then the single-supply op amp in non-inverting configuration to amplify it to the range 0..10 V. I adjust the virtual ground and the gain with two trimmer potentiometers.

The circuit is almost working, but it is producing a strange error: the output voltage is rising slowly but steadily (if it is not too close to 0 V). I have included the 100k resistor to provide a path for the bias current, but it had no use...

Any help on how to solve the problem would be appreciated.

Comment: if the output from arduino is not push-pull, then your LPF has two constants, one for charging, the other for discharging capacitor (10k vs 100k).

Comment: What time period did you simulate? Your input RC filter has a time constant of 100 ms. If you simulated for less than a couple of seconds, a slow rise or fall toward the eventual average value is exactly what you'd expect to see.

Comment: It's the potentiometer that slowly changes the gain. Just connect the 10k to GND.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič I did not use the 100k originally, and the problem mentioned was already there. I only added the 100k to solve the problem (I thought that the bias current is charging the capacitor), but unfortunately it did not help.

Comment: @ThePhoton I did not do any simulation, I have built the circuit. Yes, I set is to 100 ms intentionally. The rate of the 'slow and steady' rise of the output voltage is, say, 10 mV/s, and it happens after the desired DC voltage is set.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum But how could the potentiometer do that? I don't get it. And without a virtual ground, how can I use the single-supply op-amp?

Comment: Real ground is not any worse than virtual. And what you had is not quite virtual ground. And the potentiometer is probably slowly moving.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum OK, I think that I am missing here something. Could you please read my comment to Andy aka's answer? What is wrong with that reasoning? On the non-inverting input, the potential may be 0..5 V. If I am using the real 0 V ground instead of a 2.5V virtual ground, I am amplifying this to, say, 0..10 V. OK, but I use this op amp in 'single supply mode', so the mean of the two supply potentials (0 V and 12 V) will be added to 0..10 V, and finally I will get 6 V..16 V on the output (in practice, only 6 V..11 V, because the amplifier is not rail to rail). What am I missing?

Comment: Andy is right about everything. You need to learn the OPAMP circuits. If you have negative feedback, on both inputs the voltge is the same. The current flowing in your 10K is same as in 20K. So the gain is 1+20/10=3.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum I understand that. If the potentiometer is set to 20k, the gain will be 3, but if I set it to center, the gain will be 2 (and that's how I'd like to use the circuit), that's why I've written 0..10 V. But that's not the problem. If I use the op amp with single supply Vs, the potential offset of the output will be Vs/2 above system ground. Don't you agree with that? In TI single supply op amp tutorials, they are using virtual grounds at Vs/2 and I think I understand why. I just don't think that I can leave out the virtual ground without losing half of the input dynamic range.

Comment: Please, just read again what i wrote. Promise, it's there.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum Okay now that I calculated the circuit thoroughly, I realized that virtual ground is really not needed here, thank you. It is needed in single supply circuits which amplify AC signals, because there the AC signal needs to be biased before amplification. But this is not the case here. I will connect the 10k resistor to the ground directly.

Answer (score 1):

Just tie the bottom end of the 10k resistor (on the inverting input) to 0V and see what happens - it should work just fine like this. Trying to create an offset with the two 1k resistors is missing the point of what this circuit is intended to do.

Also, you might struggle to get all the way up to +10V on the output with only a +12V supply.

Comment: I thought that I have to create a virtual ground (potential: 2.5V) in this case (single supply op amp). The DC potential on the non-inverting input is 0..5 V (this is the smoothed PWM signal). Then, the op amp 'subtracts' the potential of the virtual ground (2.5V) from the smoothed PWM signal (so it is -2.5V..2.5V), 'multiplies' it with the gain (so it is, say, -5V..5V), and then this is added to half the supply voltage (12V/2=6 V), so on the output it is 1V..11V. What am I missing? Yes the op amp is not rail to rail, but I can increase the supply voltage, that is not a problem.

Comment: Thank you, Andy, I realized you're right (see my comment to the original question), I will modify the circuit and see what happens.